# Wcf: управление таймером

Tags: c#, таймер, wcf

Доброго времени суток. Не получается управлять таймером через сервис `wcf`. 
Описал интерфейс

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IComands
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Stop();

    [OperationContract]   
    void Start();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetLines();

}
```

описал конфиг

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <startup> 
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="scobeboard">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetUrl=""/>
       </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="ConsoleApplicationScobeboard.NewWriter"behaviorConfiguration="scobeboard" >

      <endpoint address="" binding="netHttpBinding"       contract="ConsoleApplicationScobeboard.IComands"/>
       <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:10001"/>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10002"/>            
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>

     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>

   </configuration>
```

В классе пишу

```
    void IComands.Stop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("stop");

    }
```

Но увы таймер ни как не реагирует, хотя  метод вызывается.

---

проблема решена может кому то пригодится, ошибка была в том что я явно создал объект